# Разворот словаря

Tags: python, словари

Имеется словарь вида:

```
d = {'one': 'a', 'two': ['b', 'c'], 'three': ['d']}
```

Необходимо с помощью функций реализовать разворот (смену местами ключа и значения(ий)). Как пример, исходный словарь должен был преобразован так:

```
d = {'a': 'one', 'b':'two', 'c':'two', 'd':'three'}
```

Эта же функция должна уметь сворачивать его обратно, чтобы получить исходный словарь. Кроме того, необходимо реализовать разворот одной пары (по ключу).
Я смог реализовать разворот в одну сторону, но обратно почему-то не работает. Кроме того, не работает реверс конкретной пары, если в значении содержится список.

```
def reverse(r):
    if r == 'all':
        result = {}
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    result[item] = key
            else:
                result[value] = key
        return result
    else:
        d[d.pop(r)] = r
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неоптимизированная версия:

```
def reverse_dict(d):
    result = {}
    for k, vv in d.items():
        if type(vv) is not list:
            vv = [vv]
        for v in vv:
            if v in result:
                if type(result[v]) is list:
                    result[v].append(k)
                else:
                    result[v] = [result[v], k]
            else:
                result[v] = k
    return result

d = {'one': 'a', 'two': ['b', 'c'], 'three': ['d']}
for _ in range(4):
    print(d)
    d = reverse_dict(d)
```

Вывод:

```
{'one': 'a', 'two': ['b', 'c'], 'three': ['d']}
{'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'two', 'd': 'three'}
{'one': 'a', 'two': ['b', 'c'], 'three': 'd'}
{'a': 'one', 'b': 'two', 'c': 'two', 'd': 'three'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Обратно работает, но:

- невозможно отличить случай, когда в ключ преобразована строка, от случая, когда в ключ преобразован список из одной строки, с этим вы ничего не сможете сделать, это необратимое преобразование
- чтобы корректно обработать случай с повторяющимися ключами вам нужно не просто присваивать `result[value] = key`, а проверять нет ли уже значения в `result[value]`, если значение есть, то нужно проверить список ли это, если ещё не список - сделать из него список, а далее добавить в этот список очередное значение